# Go to previous window tab when click on back button using javascript

Tags: javascript, window, back

I am using a popup with the button **Go detail** which moves to the next URL page and on the next page I added the **Back** button and when clicking on the **Back** button I want to go back to the previous window page using javascript. here is my function in javascript code but it's not working:

```
<script>
    function goBack() {
        
        window.history.back();
        
    }
</script>
```

HTML button :

```
 <button id="back" onclick="goBack()">BACK</button>
```

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: @inuryyev no sir

Comment: @inuryyev when use alert(window.history.back()); , it shows undefined in alert

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button  onclick="window.history.back()">BACK</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example works for me (see the snippet below). Perhaps the problem is in another part of the code that you didn't include in your question.

```js
function goBack () {
  window.history.back();
}

function goDetail () {
  const url = new URL('#detail', window.location.href);
  window.location.href = url.href;
}

function handleHashChange () {
  const hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
  document.querySelector('h1').textContent = hash || 'first page';

  const button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.textContent = hash === 'detail' ? 'back' : 'detail';
  button.onclick = hash === 'detail' ? goBack : goDetail;
}

function init () {
  goDetail();
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleHashChange);
}

init();
```

```html
<h1>detail page</h1>
<button id="back" onclick="goBack()">BACK</button>
```